# Raspberry Pi 4 slow USB write speed

Tags: usb, raspberrypi, usb-drive

I have a Pi 4 running Ubuntu 20.04 64 bit

Have a USB 3.0 external HDD through a powered USB hub that gets 250MB/s write speed on my MacBook

On the Pi if I try to transfer one file it transfer at 50MB/s
If I transfer 5 files simultaneously they each are at 50MB/s getting 250MB/s total

Any ideas why the single file transfer is so slow? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try the same with Raspbian?  How do you measure the speeds?

Comment: @PierreALBARÈDE I have not yet, that is on the list of things to try out though.  Will report back if I do that one. Thanks!

Comment: Any updates on this ???

Comment: Sorry wasn't able to figure it out @Ely